# Swift - How to make an integer conform to a D6?

Tags: swift, int, swift-protocols, dice

I am wondering how to make a `Int` conform to a `d6` (Die value).

I'd like to do it through a protocol; but I'm not quite sure how to make the Int follow the rules of a d6; that is to say,

- The Int can only be in the range of 1-6
- The value can be decreased but only within the range of 1-6
- It can be "rolled" (*in real terms: randomly generates a value*)

*Context*: I have a program where there are an array of `orders`, which are filled with Integers created by a randomised `d6` generated by Gameplaykit.

As per:

```
// Fill array with 3 existingOrders
let orders = [Order(), Order(), Order()]

orders.forEach { (order) in
    print (order.value)
}

// Order struct ---- 
struct Order {
    enum State: Int {
        case existingOrder = 0, completedOrder
    }

    private (set) var value: Int // I want this value to conform to a `d6` protocol

   var state: Order.State

      init() {
          self.value = Die.roll
          self.state = .existingOrder
      }

 }
```

Leveraging Gameplaykit, we generate a randomised number

```
 struct Die: Equatable {
    public static var roll: Int {
       let d6 = GKRandomDistribution.d6()
       return (d6.nextInt())
    }
}
```

So I'm wanting to make the `value` in the Order struct conform to a d6 protocol.

At first I thought I could just do this.

```
protocol Rollable {
    func roll() -> Int
}

struct D6: Rollable {
    var value: Int

    func roll() -> Int {
        let d6 = GKRandomDistribution.d6()
        return (d6.nextInt())
    }

    init() {
        self.value = roll() // throws error: self used before all stored properties
    }

    mutating func decrease(by amount: Int) {
        guard (self.value > 0) else { return }
        self.value -= amount
    }
}
```

However its not a protocol; also it throws an error:

> error: self used before all stored properties

Thus, my query is -- is it possible to force the `value: Int` inside the `Order` struct to conform to a `d6` protocol where the d6:

- Must be between 1-6
- Can be reduced in value between 1-6
- Can be rolled (generates a random new die roll)

With thanks

Edit: Tried to do it in an associated type

```
protocol Die {
    associatedtype d6 = Int
    var value: d6 { get set }
    func roll() -> d6
}
```

Not sure if this is right though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a protocol for value here, rather use dependency injection to set what GKRandomDistribution to use. My solution doesn't use your `Rollable` protocol but of course you can extract a protocol from this solution if you want.

```
class Dice {
    let randomDistribution: GKRandomDistribution
    private(set) var value: Int

    init(_ randomDistribution: GKRandomDistribution) {
        self.randomDistribution = randomDistribution
        value = 0
        self.roll()
    }

    func roll() {
        value = randomDistribution.nextInt()
    }

    func decrease(by amount: Int) {
        guard (self.value >= randomDistribution.lowestValue + amount) else { return }
        self.value -= amount
    }

}
```